# Qlikview Macro: Getting a value from a chart

Tags: macros, qlikview

I have a chart of emails and I'm trying to get the emails from the chart in order to send an email to specific people. So far this is what I have in my macro but it doesn't seem to work:

```
  set email = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("CH63").GetCell(13,2)
  ActiveDocument.Variables("TOEmail").SetContent email.text, true
  ToAdd = TOEmail 

  sendMail Message , "RoadRunner Supplier Report - CR000U" , PATH & "CR000U " & DateToday &".xls" , ToAdd , CcAdd
```

Where CH63 is my chart with emails and ToAdd is the variable that holds the emails.

Comment: Please could you provide some more details on why the above code does not work? Thank you.